# Wordpress- Elementor unable to use HTML tags in a text widget. They get escaped

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

I have a Widget in Elementor that I enter text into and it won't recognize HTML tags. For example when I write this in the text box in Elementor:

```
Our Information Security Services include: <br>• Security & Risk Assessment (Asset Classification, 
Use Cases Design & Development) <br>• Penetration Testing Services <br>• Security Monitoring & Response 
Services • SOC Managed Security Services (MSSP) <br>• SOC Architecture, Design & Operation
```

The output on the website is like this:

> Our Information Security Services include: <br>• Security & Risk Assessment (Asset Classification,
> Use Cases Design & Development) <br>• Penetration Testing Services <br>• Security Monitoring & Response
> Services • SOC Managed Security Services (MSSP) <br>• SOC Architecture, Design & Operation

Meaning it's showing html tags as plain text. Also if I try to enter a new line just by pressing the Enter key that doesn't produce a new line either. How do I make it do line breaks? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of security functions used in thus plugin which prevent HTML output and render it as a clear text. Here you can:

1. Avoid using tags
2. Switch to another plugin/extension
3. Manually remove usage of filtering function(s)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).